# How to execute two cucumber steps in parallel

Tags: automated-tests, cucumber

I need to execute one automated test step, while also another step should be running, so two checks should be run in parallel.

AND option I can not use, because it is two different steps in code

*Example: check that car is driving and doors are closed **at the same time**.*

Is any options available to execute two cucumber steps in parallel?

Comment: Question could do with a bit more work on its clarity and perhaps more detail on WHAT you want to do and WHY you need to do it.

Comment: You cannot run two scenarios at once and have them interact with each other. What you need to do is think about writing a single scenario in which both things can happen at the same time. To give further advice I would need more detail in the question

Comment: @diabolist thanks for your reply. I added example in description, hope it helps to understand.

Comment: You don't need to run things in parallel to check that the car is driving and the doors are closed. You can just check them serially with a short time frame between each check. Check doors, check driving, check doors, check driving ... proves the car is driving and the doors are closed.